# Helpme to Convert from SQL to linq Nested lambda Expression with EntityFramework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4, lambda, sql-to-linq-conversion

I´m trying to bring some Data from SQL but I cant do it with Linq, in T-SQL this Work:

```
select *
from MTRBatch MB
Inner Join MTR M on MB.Id = M.MTRBatchId
Inner JOIN MTRHeats MH on M.Id = MH.MTRId
LEFT OUTER JOIN Vendor V on MB.VendorId = v.Id
Inner Join Manufacturer MF on MB.ManufacturerId = MF.Id
Where MB.ManufacturerId = 1
AND MH.Heat = 'z01'
```

I need All the tree but with that filter.

I try this but didnt work :

```
MTRBatches
.Include(x => x.MTRs.Select(m => m.MTRHeats))
.Include(x => x.Manufacturer)
.Include(x => x.Vendor)
.Where(x => (x.Manufacturer.Id == 1));
.Where(x => x.MTRs.Any(m => m.MTRHeats.Any(h => h.Heat == 'z01')));
```

Comment: Didn't work as in...? Wrong result? Crash burn? Didn't compile?

Comment: The result is not correct:
It brings me All the MTR, it´s like the MH.HEat filter didnt happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help; `dataContext` is the name of your instance of `Entity Framework container`.

```
var result = dataContext.MTRBatches
    .Join(dataContext.MTRs,
        mb => mb.Id,
        mtr => mtr.MTRBatchId,
        (mb, mtr) => new{ Batch = mb, MTR = mtr })
    .Join(dataContext.MTRHeats,
        x => x.MTR.Id,
        mh => mh.MTRId,
        (x, mh) => new{ Batch = x.Batch, MTR = x.MTR, Heat = mh })
    .Join(dataContext.Vendors.DefaultIfEmpty(),
        x => x.Batch.VendorId,
        v => v.Id,
        (x, v) => new{ Batch = x.Batch, MTR = x.MTR, Heat = x.Heat, Vendor = v })
    .Join(dataContext.Manufacturers,
        x => x.Batch.ManufacturerId,
        mf => mf.Id,
        (x, mf) => new{ Batch = x.Batch, MTR = x.MTR, Heat = x.Heat, Vendor = x.Vendor, Manufacturer = mf})
    .Where(x => x.Manufacturer.Id == 1 && x.Heat.Heat == "z01");
```